# How can I effectively read and compare large amounts of data uploaded to a server?

Tags: php

I'm writing a simple script that compares two files and returns matches between the files. The files are CSV and txt files that just contain user's emails. I need to compare the files and return a seperate file with matching emails between the files. My script works with small amounts of data of maybe 1000 emails and returns the correct results. However, once the data becomes too large (over 1000 emails) the script never finishes and returns nothing.

I've tried to load the data all at once and then read it with PHP but this causes a crash. So currently I'm just having the script read the file line by line and then close the file. This gives me no errors but also no results when the data files are too large.

I'd like to note that I hardcoded file 'a.txt' and 'b.txt' for testing purposes but normally I would access it using $_FILES. The files are uploaded by the user via a form and I move it from temp folder to an uploads/ folder.

Here is the script:

```php
<?php
// debug helper function
function debug_to_console($data)
{
    $output = $data;
    if (is_array($output))
        $output = implode(',', $output);

    echo "console.log( 'Debug Objects: " . $output . "' );";
}

if (isset($_POST['comcsvb'])) {
    // Allow automatic detection of line endings
    ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', true);

    //Array that will hold the lines that match
    $matches = array();

    //Opening the two files on read mode
    $a_handle = fopen('uploads/a.txt', "r");
    $b_handle = fopen('uploads/b.txt', "r");

    //Iterate the first file one line at the time
    while (($a_line = fgets($a_handle)) !== false) {

        //For each line on the first file, iterate the second file a line at a time
        while (($b_line = fgets($b_handle)) !== false) {

            //remove any whitespace or new line from the beginning or the end of string
            $b_keyword = trim($b_line);

            //Check if the first file's line contains the second file's on any position
            // using case insensitive comparison
            if (preg_match("/$b_keyword/i", trim($a_line))) {
                //Add the domain line to the matches array
                $matches[] = $a_line;
            }
        }
        //Set the pointer to the beginning of the second file
        rewind($b_handle);
    }

    //Release the resources
    fclose($a_handle);
    fclose($b_handle);

    var_dump($matches);
}
```

I expect the output to be a list of emails (data) that are located in both files. The current output is nothing. I'm assuming it just loads forever. I should also mention that the e-mails are each on a new line.

```
email1@test.com
email2@test.com
email3@test.com
```

etc..

Comment: Sounds like a job for sed / awk. Used to scrub "huge" email lists against 'do not send lists' that way. [Awk - Match Values Between Two Files and Create a New File](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/305257/awk-match-values-between-two-files-and-create-a-new-file)

Comment: Thank you, this should work.

Comment: Won't find anything faster ;). Can always invoke from shell in PHP too.